# buefy input not changing border style color

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I wanted to change the style of b-input buefy but when I try changing the design it doesn't work.

Here is my code.

```
<b-field>
<b-input
placeholder="Username"
size="is-medium"
></b-input>
</b-field>


<style>
input.input.is-medium {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change all your buttons, take a look at Bulma's variables.

Buefy uses Bulma CSS

https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/button/#variables

Here, you will want to change `$button-border-color`

Comment: What would be the way to go, if I just want to change the CSS style of a specific button or a specific subset of buttons? Maybe I misunderstood the idea of bulma (and other CSS frameworks) completely, but I thought it provides me a solide base of CSS styles and I can change and override them where I need to.

Comment: Bulma creates a global theme for your application. If you need to customize a precise button, you have to create your own CSS class to override Bulma.

Comment: So for the case I need one component, looking mostly look like the others, but just a little bit modified in a way, not provided by Bulma, I have to write the style from scratch and have to try to adapt the Bulma layout?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer.

The selector seems correct, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you. Your example works in my environment (Buefy 0.9.4, Vue 2.6.10).

You might try a less specific selector:

```
input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Or... (cringe) use the important flag:

```
input.input.is-medium {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

---

To customize just a single input, try assigning a `ref` attribute to the `<b-input>` and then use JS to update the style. Note that `<b-input>` creates a `<div>` that wraps the `<input>`, so we have to go hunting for it using $el and querySelector.

Buefy HTML

```
<b-input
  ref="myInput"
  placeholder="Username"
  size="is-medium"
></b-input>
```

VueJS

```
mounted() {
  this.$refs.myInput.$el.querySelector('input').style.border = "1px solid red";
},
```